# Which ID I should use in the new GDPR API of Flurry on Android?

Tags: android, analytics, mobile-application, flurry

Flurry is offering a new GDPR API since 25th of April. This version provides the user with the right for Objection. To exercise the right within a mobile app the flurry-API-method asks for an ID of several kinds to identify the device.

We implemented the flurry SDK on Android in the way described at https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/android/

This description does not say anything about the ID which is used by the SDK on Android to identify the device when tracking it for Analytics. But somehow I would need to know which kind of ID is used by the SDK to actually use exactly the same kind of ID with the GDPR-API of Flurry.

So which kind of ID is the one to use when exercising the right of Objection for a user/device on Android when SDK is implemented as described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API takes either the GAID or AndroidId. There is not a specific way to determine ahead of time which is linked to a user. You could either make two requests, one with each type, or make a single request with both. Each request can only have a single ID of a given type, but a request can include more than one type.